# How to set height of individual bars in Ant Design Stacked Bar?

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, antd

I am using Ant Design Charts to create a stacked bar but I want it to be responsive. When I am removing data items, the bars get too thick to fill the available space. So basically, I want the bars to have fixed height so that they don't get too thick when there are few data items. Please find below the relevant images:

[image] [image]

Here is the link to ant design chart:

https://charts.ant.design/en/examples/bar/stacked#basic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pass `maxBarWidth` prop to bar config like this:

```
config = {
    maxBarWidth: 30,
    ...
```

Or directly to the `Bar` component like this:

```
<Bar {...config} maxBarWidth={30} />
```